# How do the big boys deal with api limits?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

We have an app that interacts with Facebook a lot, intensive enough to make us worry about the api limits that we know are there. My question is : How is it that some applications have like millions of users while they proactively engage with facebook and never face the api limits ? One such application is "hootsuite".

- Do they implement sophisticated load-reduction mechanism? (queues, batches and caches comes to mind)
- Does facebook somehow treat them specially? (partnership perhaps?)

Answer (score 2):

Both options are possible.

I would recommend some form of load-reduction mechanism. This could be accomplished with caching data or executing heavy queries ahead of time (possibly in a cron job of sorts).

Facebook provides some good suggestions with regard to application API rate limiting [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/api-rate-limiting/#applimit).

You can also get more information on rate limiting that is being enforced on your application by visiting this dashboard:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<app_id>/insights?ref=nav&sk=ae_<app_id>
```